# Laravel php - how to decode '?/\+-" before saving to db and encode it after?

Tags: php, laravel, urlencode

The problem
Users always add this charters ( ' \ / ? + - " ) in name of product and after this break other functions like SEO in url of product

Is there any Php or Laravel function for that?
or maybe its easy to make it model?

Thanks!

Comment: PHP base64_encode and base64_decode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Str::slug` function to create a slug. It's best if you store that in the database as well, as another field, for comparison. Then you can use the slug for the URL, and leave the name of the product as-is for use on the page.

```
$slug = \Str::slug("Bob's product has a \ / ? + - characters"); 

// Results in "bobs-product-has-a-characters"
```

Comment: THANK YOU SIR! :-)

Comment: Make sure to mark this as solved by clicking the checkbox if this solved your issue.